# JWPlayer load() and playAd() not starting using onBeforeStart()

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I can't seem to get Ads to play when calling load(). I'm using playAd() in a onBeforeStart(). When I use load() the video won't start, and either will the ad. It loads it all, and I can click start, but the video never starts automatically. I even tried $interval(jwplayer.play, 500) hehe.

It goes into IDLE mode, when I load the video - which its supposed to do(docs), but it can't start. When I remove the playAd() function, it works perfect with autostart ect.

Is it even possible? I can't find any examples of it anywhere.

Code;

```
        jwplayer('video-player').setup({
                autostart: false,
                controls: true,
                // stagevideo: true,
                debug: {
                    'levels' : 'all'
                },
                primary: 'flash',
                androidhls: true,
                icons: false,
                flashplayer: '/assets/scripts/jwplayer.flash.swf',
                html5player: '/assets/scripts/jwplayer.html5.js',
                skin: '/assets/skin/skin.xml',
                file: clip.videoUrl,
                image: clip.thumbnail640,
                wmode: 'transparent',
                height: "100%",
                width: "100%",
                repeat: "false",
                advertising: {
                    client: "vast"
                 },
                plugins: {
                    "/assets/scripts/borsenticker.js": {
                        'ticker1': tickerStringUpper,
                        'ticker2': stockString,
                        'ticker2_nofont': stockString_nofont,
                        'date': dateFiltered
                    }
                },
            });
```

load it;

```
jwplayer('video-player').load([{
                    file: clip.videoUrl,
                    image: clip.thumbnail640,
                }]);
                jwplayer('video-player').play();
```

and setups are;

```
    jwplayer('video-player').onBeforePlay(function (){
        if(!videoPlayerAdLoaded) {
            jwplayer('video-player').playAd(Preroll.getVastTag());
            videoPlayerAdLoaded = true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can I see a link to where you are running this?

Comment: Hey Ethan. Can't post the homepage here because of confidiality - so do you have an email? :)

Comment: support [at] jwplayer [dot] com

Comment: I'll ofcourse post the answers on how to solve this in this thread :)

Comment: You do have an ads license, right? You need that in order to run VAST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by updating to 6.11 from 6.10. :)